# Pandas sum then divide by unique count

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a df that looks like this:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['1/07/2019', '1/08/2019', '1/08/2019','1/07/2019', '1/08/2019', '1/09/2019', '1/07/2019', '1/07/2019'],
                     'basket_id': ['AB789', 'CD674', 'KL237', 'AB789', 'CD674', 'RS234', 'ST089', 'OP448'],
                     'product_id': ['1839', '0368', '5360', '2524', '1036', '1184', '9280', '7721'],
                   'revenue': [400, 500, 350, 200, 100, 450, 50, 150]})
print(test)
```

Now I'd like to create a df called temp_test that shows the date, sum of revenue, count of unique basket ID, and lastly a column for avg revenue per basket.

```
temp_test = test.groupby(['date']).agg({'revenue': sum, 'basket_id': 'nunique'}).reset_index()
temp_test['rev_per_basket'] = test['revenue'] / test.groupby(['date'])['basket_id'].nunique()
print(temp_test)
```

However, my rev_per_basket column only shows NaN. Ideally it should show 226.66, 475, and 450. Any ideas of what went wrong there? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want

```
temp_test['rev_per_basket'] = temp_test.revenue.divide(temp_test.basket_id)
```